# StringWriter.ToString() is breaking xml C#

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, escaping

I have a class array that I'm going to pass to XML to send it later to SQL Server Stored Procedure.
The problem is that when I execute StringWriter it adds some scape caracters (=\) that appears in the final XML.

My code is the following:

```
  public XmlDocument ToXML(object obj_to_xml)
{
    string str_XML;
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    var stringwriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj_to_xml.GetType());
    serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, obj_to_xml);**

    //at this point the format is correct, for example stringwriter contains: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfRegistroPrestamo xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <RegistroPrestamo>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Cedula>8-834-789</Cedula>
    <Nombre>Amarillos</Nombre>
    <Apellido>Perez</Apellido>
  </RegistroPrestamo>
  <RegistroPrestamo>
    <Id>0</Id>
    <Cedula />
    <Nombre />
    <Apellido />
  </RegistroPrestamo>
</ArrayOfRegistroPrestamo>

    //the problem comes with this line

    xml.LoadXml(stringwriter.ToString());

    //final XML looks like this: 
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>
<ArrayOfRegistroPrestamo xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">
  <RegistroPrestamo>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Cedula>8-834-789</Cedula>
    <Nombre>Amarillos</Nombre>
    <Apellido>Perez</Apellido>
  </RegistroPrestamo>
  <RegistroPrestamo>
    <Id>0</Id>
    <Cedula />
    <Nombre />
    <Apellido />
  </RegistroPrestamo>
</ArrayOfRegistroPrestamo>

    return xml;
}
```

When SQL Server tries to parse the XML Code:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "P_Save_Procedure";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Registros", SqlDbType.Xml).Value = xml;
```

Stored Procedure Text

```
Create procedure [dbo].[P_Save_Procedure]
(@Registros as xml)
as
begin
    select distinct 'Id' = x.v.value('Id[1]', 'Int')
    from @Registros.nodes('/ArrayOfRegistroPrestamo/RegistroPrestamo') x(v)
end
```

I got the error:

Mens. 9413, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
XML parsing: line 1, character 37; It expected a string literal

If I call the SP manually with the correct version of the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfRegistroPrestamo xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <RegistroPrestamo>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Cedula>8-834-789</Cedula>
    <Nombre>Amarillos</Nombre>
    <Apellido>Perez</Apellido>
  </RegistroPrestamo>
  <RegistroPrestamo>
    <Id>0</Id>
    <Cedula />
    <Nombre />
    <Apellido />
  </RegistroPrestamo>
</ArrayOfRegistroPrestamo>
```

The result is the expected.

Already have spend 2 days tryng to find a way to get the correct sintax for the XML and got nothing.

Comment: Do you need utf-16?  Can you use utf-8?

Comment: Can you try print xml or insert the xml in a temporary table in the procedure? Curious, what the xml string contains at Line 1 char 37. Looks like the last character in the first line. Maybe a bad line break.

Comment: Can you please give us the class definition that you're passing to ToXML? Also, how are you converting the XmlDocument to string before passing it to the stored procedure, are you using XmlDocument.Save?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this:

[DoNotEscapeUriAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.donotescapeuriattributes(v=vs.110).aspx)